# Sort XML Object by key php

Tags: php, arrays, object, simplexml

Ok so I have an XML object.

$articles, I am foreach-ing around this, like so:

```
foreach($articles as $key => $ind_article) {

}
```

The problem I have is that the values I need to access are like so:

```
$ind_article->image;
$ind_article->image2;
$ind_article->image1;
```

But I can't set the image source of the article because the key is unknown, yet I know it starts with `image`. What can I do to the array/object to either order it or display all `image` values?

Comment: "I have an XML object" - can you please be more specific? Since you're using foreach() my bets are on http://docs.php.net/simplexml but you never know...

Comment: Yes, you are right, its simplexml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($articles as $key => $ind_article) {
    $variables = get_object_vars($ind_article);
    foreach ($variables as $inner_key => $variable) {
         if (strpos($inner_key, "image") === 0) {
              echo "Found image: $variable";
              // This should also work: echo $ind_article->$inner_key;
         }
     }
}
```